# To filter Json data in alphabetical order in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

This is my (customet.component.html) file

```
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="onNameChange()">

      <div *ngFor="let s of filteredScreenshots">
           {{s | json}}
        </div>

      <mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let filteredScreen  of 
         filteredScreens ; let i = index">
          <mat-card-header>
           <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image" >
               <img mat-card-image class="list-img" src=" 
              {{filteredScreen?.img}}" >
           </div>
        <mat-card-content class="names">{{ filteredScreen?.name }}</mat-card- 
          content>
         </mat-card-header>
     </mat-card>
```

This is(customer.component.ts)file

```
            import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
            import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 
            import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
            import * as _ from 'lodash';

            @Component({
            selector: 'ylb-customer',
            templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
            })

            export class CustomerComponent  {

            spaceScreens: Array<any>;
            filteredScreens = [];
            name: string;

            constructor(private http:Http){
                this.http.get('assets/app.json').pipe(
                        map(response => response.json().screenshots)
                    )
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        this.spaceScreens = res; 
                        this.filteredScreens = res;
                });
            }

            onNameChange() {
                this.filteredScreens = _.filter(this.spaceScreens, (screenshot) => {
                    const name = screenshot['name'];
                    const filteredName = this.name.toUpperCase();
                    return name === undefined ? false : name.toUpperCase().startsWith(filteredName);
                });
            }



            }
```

this json file present inside assets folder(app.json)

```
              {   
        "screenshots":[ 

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Ramesh Kumar"
                    },

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Joe Root"
                    },

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Adam Evans"
                    }



            ]        
        }
```

Search/filter is working fine,How can i make the data present in json file to display in alphabetical order and How can i apply search for last name of the name string,i mean suppose i want to search chris woakes,how can i search it by typing only woakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took bajaran's answer and modified it to not fail when the content of a field is `null` and to work case insensitively:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: any, field: string): any[] {
        if (!array) {
            return array;
        }
        array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            if ((a[field] || '').toLowerCase() < (b[field] || '').toLowerCase()) {
                return -1;
            } else if ((a[field] || '').toLowerCase() > (b[field] || '').toLowerCase()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for improving another user's answer! Also good you gave proper credit :) However it'd be best to amend the original answer instead of copying most of it and posting it as new answer. You can edit any post, or, if you're unsure, add a comment asking OP if they'd like to add your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To Display in any alphabetical order make the custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "sort"
})
export class ArraySortPipe  implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

and used that like

```
<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let filteredScreen  of 
         filteredScreens | sort : fieldName" ; let i = index">
```

For searching the last name split that field and pass to custom search function or you can also create the pipe for same

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
      return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
}
```

Refer to below link for search functionality

[Serach pipe](https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c)

Comment: Should i need to create 2 pipes for Sort and filter ??

Comment: Or you can create one also but specify if condition in that, It is good practice to used different pipe

Comment: I am getting this error   Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'sort' could not be found ("f filteredScreens ; let i = index">

    <mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let filteredScreen  [ERROR ->]of 
    filteredScreens | sort : 'fieldName' ; let i = index">

Comment: Add that pipe class name in the app.module.ts file

Comment: import { ArraySortPipe  } from 'specify the location where your pipe is present';
import { FilterPipe }  from 'specify the location';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [ ArraySortPipe, FilterPipe ]
})

Comment: Imported in(app.modeule.ts) file.No errors but both sorting & searching(searching the last name) is not happening.

Comment: I have created pipes(filter&sort) inside a folder called shared

Comment: I have given links in (app.modules.ts) file like this

Comment: import { FilterPipe} from './shared/filter.pipe';
import { ArraySortPipe} from './shared/sort.pipe';

Comment: I want the code where you apply the sort/filter pipe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177461/discussion-between-bajran-and-shankar-guru).